# GMail addon: trigger function don't run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, gmail-addons

When I open a message my GMail add-on run trigger function and display to me some information. But if I click on another message and then return to first one, add-on display old information and doesn't run trigger function. Is it possible to run trigger function on each click on a message?

Answer (score 0):

GMail add-ons do not support triggers. [See GMail Add-on Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions).

Comment: But I activated add-on Asana and after it trigger funtion run each time, when i open a message.Each time all my add-ons reload https://gyazo.com/52a1daf27246b4ad048e4298b0690657
 I can't figure out how it works.

Comment: When you said "triggers" I assumed you meant simple or installed triggers. Not sure whats going on without seeing any code.

Comment: Sorry,  i meant function , which is in manifest file as 'onTriggerFunction'